# Rendering of PointCloud not working

Tags: rendering, point-clouds

I managed to get a point cloud into Blender 3.6 and wanted to render a view port image. But all I get is a black screen. It happens since I changed the size of the radius in the "Mesh to Points" node. Before that I could render a complete sequence of 1000 images.

The "normal" renderer (F12) renders an image with the old settings of the GN; it almost seems as there was a cache somewhere...

I have no idea why this is suddenly happening. Does anybody of you guys have n idea?

[image: Blender interface overview]

[image: Output settings]

[image: Scene settings]

[image: Modifier Geometry Node settings]

[image: This is what I would like to render]